# Trying to show/hide and element based on what option is selected in a dropdown box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to show div id='other' when option value='8' is selected in the dropdown box. I also want it to be hidden again if any other value is selected.
This is what I've come up with so far:

```
<script>
function other()
{
if (document.getElementById("type").selectedIndex="8";)
{
document.getElementById("other").style.display="block";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("other").style.display="none";
}
}
</script>
<select id='type' onchange='other()'>
<option value="0">Logo</option>
<option value="1">Banner</option>
<option value="2">Static Advert</option>
<option value="3">Forum Signature</option>
<option value="4">YouTube Banner</option>
<option value="5">YouTube Icon</option>
<option value="6">Facebook Cover</option>
<option value="7">Twitter Background</option>
<option value="8">Other (please specify)</option>
</select>
<br/>
<div style='display:none;' id='other'>
If other, specify what you would like.
<input type='text' class='text' name='type' value size='10'/>
</div>
```

Comment: You should explain what is going wrong in your post as well as give the code. You have provided no information about what is not working.

Comment: just a comment on a point : when you write if ( = "8" ), don't you mean if ( == 8 ) ?

Comment: I'd also highly suggest using jQuery to eliminate a lot of your extra code.

Comment: @thatidiotguy, the point is that I do not know what isn't working, hence the question

Comment: What is the error? Can you check the console log? Edit: Check the answer from Gaby below with jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors in line

```
if (document.getElementById("type").selectedIndex="8";)
```

1. You need to remove the `;` from there..
2. Single `=` is assignment.. For comparisons you must use `==`
3. and since `selectedIndex` is a number you should compare it with a number instead of forcing an implicit type conversion..

So

```
if (document.getElementById("type").selectedIndex==8)
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/W7qTV/